# Using a single C# SOAP webservice client access the same webservice on multiple servers

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap

The project this concerns is about uploading structured information from Excel to a java based webserver for further processing. As the least common denominator i have chosen SOAP for the job.
For this i have written a C# add-in that accesses a SOAP service on the target server. It uses a web reference to do so. This works on a test system.
In production the client will have to access three servers and these will change over time (not daily, just normal maintenance intervals). The content of a web reference is tied to a specific server, so i will need three web references and a recompile for each server change. 
My goal would be a single copy of the (restructured) web reference content so the variable content can be put in a configuration file and a server change can be effected by maintenance.
The question is the following: Has anyone of you built a solution for this? Hints and tips are welcome.

Comment: Your web reference should have an Url property somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the web reference directory contains both a .map file and a .wsdl file both containing the serverURL plus a generated .cs and .datasource file. I would like to pull out the serverURLs without toppling the generated house of cards in a way not involving writing my own generator.